# Trouble with Syntax format for Datediff - SQL

Tags: sql, data-science, data-analysis, presto

I have a syntax formatting issue with the query below. 
I am trying to get the difference between two time columns and then subtract 20 to get whatever the difference is minus 20. I also want to take the max value of either that or 0 so anything less than 0 will be 0.

```
select id, sum(max(0, (date_diff('minute', time_a, time_b))  - 20)) as mins
    FROM tbl
```

What am doing wrong in the query above that is erorring out?

Thanks!

Comment: Try removing the single quotes around `minute`.

Comment: I tried that and then it doesnt read minute I think I need the single quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum(max())` is highly suspicious.  Perhaps you intend:

```
select id, sum(greatest(0, date_diff('minute', time_a, time_b) - 20)) as mins
from tbl
```

Comment: Thanks ! So this gives me the max value of the actual difference between the 2 cols or 0? @Gordon Linoff

Comment: This sums the difference minus 20 minutes between the two times when the difference is greater than 20 minutes.